# $P_n(x):=1+ \sum_{m=1}^n\dfrac{x^m}{m!}$ has no real root for even $n$ and exactly one real root for odd $n$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is it true that 
$$P_n(x):=1+ \sum_{m=1}^n\dfrac{x^m}{m!}$$
has no real root for even $n$ and exactly one real root for odd $n$? I can only prove that the polynomial cannot have any multiple roots. Am stuck , Please Help.

Comment: Note that $P_n'(x)= P_{n-1}(x)$. I guess you can do by induction.

Comment: @John: Induction on what ? $n$ ? I am not sure ...

Comment: Its obvious that there are no positive real roots. This is an $n$-degree polynomial with positive coefficients. By Descartes Rule of Signs there are no positive real roots. This is true regardless of the value of $n$.

Comment: I dont know if its helpful but $P_n$ is also the $n$th partial sum for the Taylor series, centered at $x=0$, for the exponential function $e^x$. Just pointing that out if it helps. The exponential function is positive everywhere and thus never crosses the x-axis.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: You don't have to use Descarte's rule of signs , just simply note that $P_n(x)>o$ whenever $x>0$

Comment: Yes, user123733. Descartes Rule of Signs is a non-intuitive but plainly obvious way of deducing that. You said "simply note"... and what makes it so obvious to you? Without lacking any sense of rigor?  Its as obvious to me as it is to you, but I dont rely on intuition to prove my arguments.  If its not usable information then dont use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $S(n)$ be the statement that

> $P_n(x)$ has no real root for $n$ even, and has exactly one real roots for $n$ odd.

You can check directly that $S(1)$ and $S(2)$ are true.

Assume that $S(k)$ is true. Consider $k+1$-case:

- if $k$ is even, the induction hypothesis says that $P_k(x)$ has no real roots. As $P_k(0) = 1$, we have $P_k(x) >0$ for all $x$. As $P_{k+1}'(x) = P_k(x)$, then $P_{k+1}(x)$ is strictly increasing and so $P_{k+1}(x)$ has only one real root (Need to check the asymptotics here).
- if $k$ is odd, then there is $y\in \mathbb R$ so that $P_k(x) <0$ , $\forall x<y$, $P_k(y) = 0$ and $P_k(z) >0$ , $\forall z>y$. Then as $P_{k+1}'(x)= P_k(x)$, then $P_{k+1}(x)$ has a strict minimum at $y$. Note that $y\neq 0$. As

$$P_{k+1} (y) = P_k(y) + \dfrac{y^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} = \dfrac{y^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}>0$$

as $y\neq 0$ and $k+1$ is even. Thus $P_{k+1}$ is always positive and has no real root.

Thus $S(k+1)$ is true. By induction, the statement is true for all $n$.

Comment: form $P_k(y)=0$ how do you conclude that $P_k(x)<0$ for $x<y$ ? It might happen that $P_k$ is +ve everywhere else , looking like an U curve passing through the origin .

Comment: I use implicitly the fact that $P_k$ tends to $-\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$ and $P_k(x) \to\infty $ as $x \to \infty$. @user123733

Comment: The inequalities follow only from that ?

Comment: Yes. If there is $x<y$ so that $P_k(x)>0$, then as $P_k(x')<0$ for some $x'<x$, there is $x''$ between $x'$ and $x$ so that $P_k(x'')=0$ (IVT). @user123733

Comment: @user99914 What did you mean by "need to check the asymptotics"?