# Proving Modified Taylor expansion of $e^x$ (negative sign for odd powers) is always positive when n is EVEN.

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Can we prove that the following sequence is always positive for EVEN $n$ and for positive real $x$. The sequence is very similar to Taylor expansion of $e^x$, but negative signs for odd exponents:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i(-1)^i}{i!}=1-\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} ... $$

for small $n$, it is easy to show, but I need proof for every EVEN $n$. I tried Induction, but I cannot finish. If somebody knows how to prove by Induction or by any other method, please explain it to me.
Thanks for Everyone!
This is my first post, sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: I am fairly sure that I have seen this before. The idea is to show with induction that the Taylor polynomials of the exponential function are positive for even n, and strictly increasing for odd n.

Comment: Here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1033544.

Comment: This is just $e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that your polynomial is the Taylor approximant of $e^{-x}$. Let us define:

$$
f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}.
$$

Your polynomial is simply $f_n(-x)$. Now by Taylor's remainder formula in the form of Lagrange, there exist a $\xi\in (0,x)$

$$
f(x):=e^{x} = f_n(x) +  \frac{ e^\xi x^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}.
$$

Now send $x\to -x$ to obtain

$$
e^{-x} = f_n(-x) + \frac{ e^\xi (-x)^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}.
$$

for $\xi \in (-x,0)$. From this, if $n$ is even, we derive

$$
f_n(-x) = e^{-x} + \frac{ e^\xi x^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)!},
$$

which is a sum of two positive quantities when $x$ is positive.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it should be $ e^{-x} = f_n(x) + \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} (-e^{-\theta})$.

Comment: @MartinR yes thanks. I made it a bit clearer.